# How do I keep android SDK and reuse it on other PCs without the internet

Tags: android-sdk

I am fresh-from-the-oven kind of new to android and I just downloaded the android studio which is a whooping 683mb, after downloading it, I noticed it didn't come with SDK and that it was going to download a whole other stuff that is sized around 1.5gb, It was the second "baddest" news since the 1993 Apple Newton announcement. Why this bothers me is because I format my PC every now and then because of some reason, meaning I'll always have to go through this daunting process quite frequently.

I then figured I had to download the portable version with the believe that when  android studio downloads the SDK, it will be inside the folder where the portable version was extracted, then I'll copy the whole folder with the downloaded SDK and zip it and keep safely.

My question is this, will it work, is this the right thing to do, when I extract it to a new PC, does it re-download SDK and those other monstrously large stuff.

Thanks.

Comment: Development questions are off topic here. See Stackoverflow.com and specially this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48127340/android-studio-files-backup-on-linux).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have separate partition for Android Studio and SDK and it works fine after Installling my OS again & again.

Process is simple

1. Download zip version of Android Studio.
2. Open Android Studio for the first time
3. Select Advance/Custom option.
4. Select your SDK location (For the first time AS will download SDK for you if you have not downloaded yet)
5. Done!!!

Now if you will copy your SDK and Studio to another PC then you can choose your SDK location during first run and it won't download again.